# Proving the product rule for the formal derivative over $F[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives

I am trying to prove that the formal derivative of a polynomial in $F[X]$, defined by:

$$P'(X) := \sum_{i \in \mathbb N}(i+1)a_{i+1}X^i$$
satisfies the product rule such that for the derivation operator $D$: 
$$D(P(X)*Q(X)) = D(P(X))* Q(X) + P(X)*D(Q(X))$$

I tried doing the proof, by using the definition of products of polynomials over $F[X]$ (Cauchy - Product) and started with: $$D(\sum_{j \in \mathbb N} (\sum_{i=0}^k a_ib_{k-i})X^j) = \sum_{j \in \mathbb N}(j+1)(\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} a_ib_{k-i})X^j$$

when I try simplifying further, I get lost at some point and I am not even sure whether or not this is the right approach to prove this, since it is pretty messy. Is there another easy way of proving this, and would this approach that I took work as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof will come out if you now attack the right hand side.

Alternatively use the linearity. If we have the result for $P$ and $Q_1$, and $P$ and  $Q_2$ we have it for $P(Q_1+Q_2)$. Likewise for fixed $Q$ and $P_1, P_2$. Constants clearly are irrelevant.

That means it is sufficient to prove the result for $P=x^m$ and $Q=x^n$ which is easy.